# Manga about a boy who sacrifices himself to protect his parents from bandits, but is saved by a dragon

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga, isekai

It's an isekai manga about a boy who is headed to another town with his family and their friends when they are attacked by bandits. While being attacked he has to help his dad protect his mom, who can't use her magic properly because she is pregnant. While protecting her, he has to sacrifice himself to stop the last bandit by throwing him and the bandit over a cliff. A mysterious force saved him from dying when he fell over the cliff and he found out the mysterious force was a dragon, but at the time of meeting the dragon he couldn't tell it was a dragon because the dragon looked... odd.

After the dragon was able to send him back to his parents, the dragon died and upon dying she embedded her will on him. Now that he has the dragon's will and is in the forest he comes upon a group of human traffickers that are kidnapping an elven princess. He saves the princess and takes her back home, but her grandfather takes a liking to him and decides to train him...

Does anyone know the name of this manga? I think it just recently became an anime as well.

Comment: In what way was this work *isekai*?  Your description contains no reference to any characters coming from other worlds.

Comment: @jwodder - If it's the same manga as the one I submitted in my answer, the main character is initially an adult king in a high-tech world with medieval trappings, who is assassinated, and then wakes up as a newborn infant in a much less technologically-advanced world where magic-users are commonplace.

Comment: @Lauren - If my answer below is correct, please mark it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. It will reward me with some [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), and helps with the administration of the site. Also, please consider [upvoting](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) the answer as well, if you haven't already. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is *[The Beginning After The End](https://tbate.fandom.com/wiki/The_Beginning_After_The_End_Wiki)*.

[image]

Plot points that match your description:

- The protagonist, a small boy named [Arthur](https://tbate.fandom.com/wiki/Arthur_Leywin), is travelling to a town with his parents and some others, when their group attacked by bandits.
- Arthur and his mother have magical powers, but she can't use hers now because she's pregnant.
- During the struggle, Arthur is knocked off a cliff, but manages to take the last remaining bandit with him.
- Arthur wakes up at the bottom off the cliff, and discovers he's been saved by a mysterious being calling herself [Sylvia](https://tbate.fandom.com/wiki/Sylvia).
- When he meets Sylvia in person, she initially appears as a giant humanoid clad in black armour. She later reveals her true form, that of a white dragon.
- Sylvia opens a portal to send Arthur back to his parents, at the cost of her own life. (She has a wound in her chest that gets worse the more she uses her powers.)
- As a parting gift, Sylvia infuses her unique 'will' onto Arthur, stating that his future development as a mage depends on how well he uses this gift.
- After going through the portal, Arthur finds himself in a forest, where he saves an elven princess named [Tessia](https://tbate.fandom.com/wiki/Tessia_Eralith) from a group of bandits.
- Arthur accompanies Tessia to her home, where he meets her family, including [her grandfather](https://tbate.fandom.com/wiki/Virion_Eralith), who decides to train him.

Comment: If this answer is correct, please upvote it and mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark just beneath the voting arrows.